# delete the output of a join (record in multipe tables)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, cloud-foundry, cascading-deletes

I use

```
select * 
from 
    service_instances i 
    inner join 
    service_instance_operations op on i.id = op.service_instance_id 
    inner join 
    service_bindings bind on i.id = bind.service_instance_id  
where i.guid = 'daf67426-129b-4010-832c-692bcfe98f62';
```

Howto delete this record in all 3 tables? There are primary and foreign key constraints.

It doesn't work to replace "select *" with "delete".

DB schema is CCDB from Cloud Foundry [cloud_controller_ng](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng).

Comment: Would it be an option to make the FK's ON DELETE CASCADE? Otherwise you basically will have to do three deletes.

Comment: I didn't do the DB design. It's an app downloaded off GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `WITH` construction.

```
with _deleted_service_instances as (
    delete from service_instances 
    where guid = 'daf67426-129b-4010-832c-692bcfe98f62'
    returning id
)
, _deleted_service_instance_operations as (
    delete from service_instance_operations op
    using _deleted_service_instances i
        where op.service_instance_id = i.id
)
, _deleted_service_bindings as (
    delete from service_bindings b
    using _deleted_service_instances i
        where b.service_instance_id = i.id
)
select null::int as dummy;
```

**UPDATE**

> I use PostgreSQL 9.0.3 and can't upgrade because of vendor. It was released 2011-01-31. Do you know how the query looks with my version?

I see only one way - is to use three queries:

```
    delete from service_instance_operations op
    using service_instances i
    where op.service_instance_id = i.id
            AND i.guid = 'daf67426-129b-4010-832c-692bcfe98f62';

    delete from service_bindings b
    using service_instances i
    where b.service_instance_id = i.id
            AND i.guid = 'daf67426-129b-4010-832c-692bcfe98f62';

    delete from service_instances 
    where guid = 'daf67426-129b-4010-832c-692bcfe98f62';
```

Comment: I use `PostgreSQL 9.0.3` and can't upgrade because of vendor. It was released 2011-01-31. Do you know how the query looks with my version?

Comment: See an update in the answer. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for update. From Postgres Docs: `Compatibility
This command conforms to the SQL standard, except that the USING and RETURNING clauses are PostgreSQL extensions, as is the ability to use WITH with DELETE.`. That's why didn't know about it, it does not exist in Oracle.